# regular expression for a url in node.js express routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, url-routing

I am working on building node.js server which uses regular expression for routing.

**The URL which has to captured in node.js using regex**

```
www.domain.com/people-images-taken-on-December-05-2011/
```

`The people-images-taken-on-` is fixed in the **URL**. I only wanted to capture month, date and year.

I will capturing the above URL in express like below

```
app.get('/people-images-taken-on-{only alphabets}-{2 digits}-{4 digits} ',
```

I found the regex each patterns separately

```
allows only alphabets - [a-zA-Z]+$
allows a 4 digits value - (\\d){4}
allows a 2 digits value - (\\d){2}
```

I tried to combine everything, But I failed miserably many times. Can any one give the correct regex for the url patern? Also can anyone tell me this regex based path handling is a good way for handling Dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [named parameters with custom regular expressions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#custom-match-parameters), like this:

```
app.get('/people-images-taken-on-:month([a-zA-Z]+)-:day(\\d{2})-:year(\\d{4})', ...)
```

This will store the values in `req.params` like this:

```
{ month: 'December', day: '05', year: '2011' }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot helping